# Clarification on Singleton Pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm writing some utility classes for a PHP app and a lot of them will be singletons.  Found myself re-writing the same code over and over, and decided to make an abstract base class `Singleton` and subclass it. Just want to make sure I've done this correctly!

```
abstract class Singleton
{
    private static $instance = NULL;

    public static final function getInstance()
    {
        if(self::$instance == NULL)
            self::$instance = instantiate();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    protected abstract static function instantiate();
}

class LogHelper extends Singleton
{
    protected static final function instantiate()
    {
        return new LogHelper();
    }
}
```

Now, if I have done this correctly, I can call `LogHelper $LOGGER = LogHelper::getInstance()` from anywhere in my codebase, and get a reference to the same instance every time, yes?

Comment: This is similar to what Ruby provides as a mixin.  I'd also follow @jesse's suggestions

Comment: [Why Singletons have no use in PHP](http://gooh.posterous.com/singletons-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to define your getInstance() methods as static so that you can access them without having to instantiate the class. Then, you'll use this:

```
$objSingleton = LogHelper::getInstance();
```

And, you'll probably want to define a private constructor:

```
private function __construct() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

While singletons seem like the ideal solution at first, they are not. Learn about registries and dependecy injection; they will make your life easier when you start unit testing.